# ReyclerView using multiple type view doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am developing an Android application in Kotlin and I implemented a RecyclerView.

Each item of this RecyclerView contains one of the 3 combinations below:

- a TextView + a TextView
- a TextView + a Button
- a TextView + a Spinner

My problem is simply that nothing is displayed! I don't understand my mistake, can you help me?

Here is my adapter:

```
class CustomAdapter(private val dataSet: Array<Parameter>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    sealed class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        class TextViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val textViewName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterName)
            val textViewValue: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterValue)
        }
        class ButtonViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
            var textViewName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterName)
            val buttonViewValue: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterButton)
        }
        class SpinnerViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val textViewName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterName)
            val spinnerViewValue: Spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterSpinner)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            0 -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.parameter_text, viewGroup, false)
                ViewHolder.TextViewHolder(view)
            }
            1 -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.parameter_button, viewGroup, false)
                ViewHolder.ButtonViewHolder(view)
            }
            2 -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.parameter_spinner, viewGroup, false)
                ViewHolder.SpinnerViewHolder(view)
            }
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (viewHolder) {
            is ViewHolder.TextViewHolder -> {
                viewHolder.textViewName.text = dataSet[position].parameterName
                viewHolder.textViewValue.text = dataSet[position].parameterValue as CharSequence?
            }
            is ViewHolder.ButtonViewHolder -> {
                viewHolder.textViewName.text = dataSet[position].parameterName
                viewHolder.buttonViewValue.text = dataSet[position].parameterValue as CharSequence?
            }
            is ViewHolder.SpinnerViewHolder -> {
                viewHolder.textViewName.text = dataSet[position].parameterName
                viewHolder.spinnerViewValue.adapter = dataSet[position].parameterValue as SpinnerAdapter?
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) : Int {
        return dataSet[position].parameterType
    }


    override fun getItemCount() = dataSet.size
}
```

Each of the different types of parameters inherited from the class Parameter:

```
open class Parameter(open var parameterName: String? = "", open var parameterType: Int = 0, open var parameterValue: Any) {
}
```

ParameterText class:

```
class ParameterText(override var parameterName: String?, override var parameterValue: Any = "") : Parameter(parameterName, parameterValue = parameterValue!!) {
    override var parameterType: Int = 0
}
```

ParameterButton class:

```
class ParameterButton(override var parameterName: String?, override var parameterValue: Any = "") : Parameter(parameterName, parameterValue = parameterValue!!) {
    override var parameterType: Int = 1
}
```

ParameterSpinner class:

```
class ParameterSpinner(override var parameterName: String?, override var parameterValue: Any) : Parameter(parameterName, parameterValue = parameterValue) {
    override var parameterType: Int = 2
}
```

In the OnCreate method, I initialize the RecyclerView:

```
rv_parameters.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
rv_parameters.adapter = CustomAdapter(parametersList)
```

Here is my list of parameters:

```
private val parametersList = emptyArray<Parameter>()
```

And finally, here is how I add parameters to this list:

```
append(parametersList, ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C"))
```

Using this method:

```
fun append(arr: Array<Parameter>, element: Parameter): Array<Parameter?> {
    val array = arrayOfNulls<Parameter>(arr.size + 1)
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, array, 0, arr.size)
    array[arr.size] = element
    return array
}
```

**EDIT 1:** (following Tenfour04's answer)

My adapter:

```
class CustomAdapter(private var dataSet: List<Parameter?>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    sealed class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        class TextViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val textViewName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterName)
            val textViewValue: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterValue)
        }
        class ButtonViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
            var textViewName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterName)
            val buttonViewValue: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterButton)
        }
        class SpinnerViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val textViewName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterName)
            val spinnerViewValue: Spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parameterSpinner)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            0 -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.parameter_text, viewGroup, false)
                ViewHolder.TextViewHolder(view)
            }
            1 -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.parameter_button, viewGroup, false)
                ViewHolder.ButtonViewHolder(view)
            }
            2 -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.parameter_spinner, viewGroup, false)
                ViewHolder.SpinnerViewHolder(view)
            }
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (viewHolder) {
            is ViewHolder.TextViewHolder -> {
                viewHolder.textViewName.text = dataSet[position]!!.parameterName
                viewHolder.textViewValue.text = dataSet[position]!!.parameterValue as CharSequence?
            }
            is ViewHolder.ButtonViewHolder -> {
                viewHolder.textViewName.text = dataSet[position]!!.parameterName
                viewHolder.buttonViewValue.text = dataSet[position]!!.parameterValue as CharSequence?
            }
            is ViewHolder.SpinnerViewHolder -> {
                viewHolder.textViewName.text = dataSet[position]!!.parameterName
                viewHolder.spinnerViewValue.adapter = dataSet[position]!!.parameterValue as SpinnerAdapter?
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) : Int {
        return dataSet[position]!!.parameterType
    }


    override fun getItemCount() = dataSet.size
}
```

In the OnCreate method, I initialize the RecyclerView:

```
rv_parameters.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
rv_parameters.adapter = CustomAdapter(parametersList)
```

Here is my list of parameters:

```
private var parametersList = emptyList<Parameter?>()
```

And finally, here is how I add parameters to this list:

```
with(rv_parameters.adapter) {
    parametersList += ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C")
    this?.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not in Kotlin I think it will be helpful for you

public class BeneficiaryIndicatorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

```
private List<Indicator> dataSet;
private Context mContext;

public BeneficiaryIndicatorAdapter(List<Indicator> dataSet, Context mContext) {
    this.dataSet = dataSet;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

public static class EdittextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    AppCompatTextView indicator_number, indicator_en_tv, indicator_bn_tv, save_tv;
    TextInputEditText answer_tf;
    public EdittextViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.indicator_number = itemView.findViewById (R.id.indicator_number);
        this.indicator_en_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.indicator_en_tv);
        this.indicator_bn_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.indicator_bn_tv);
        this.answer_tf = itemView.findViewById (R.id.answer_tf);
        this.save_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.save_tv);



    }
}

public static class DatePickerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    AppCompatTextView indicator_number, indicator_en_tv, indicator_bn_tv, select_date_tv, save_tv;
    RelativeLayout transaction_date_layout;

    public DatePickerHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.indicator_number = itemView.findViewById (R.id.indicator_number);
        this.indicator_en_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.indicator_en_tv);
        this.indicator_bn_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.indicator_bn_tv);
        this.select_date_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.select_date_tv);
        this.transaction_date_layout = itemView.findViewById (R.id.transaction_date_layout);
        this.save_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.save_tv);
    }
}

public static class SpinnerPickerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    AppCompatTextView indicator_number, indicator_en_tv, indicator_bn_tv, save_tv;
    AppCompatSpinner answerSpinner;
    public SpinnerPickerHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.indicator_number = itemView.findViewById (R.id.indicator_number);
        this.indicator_en_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.indicator_en_tv);
        this.indicator_bn_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.indicator_bn_tv);
        this.answerSpinner = itemView.findViewById (R.id.answerSpinner);
        this.save_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.save_tv);
    }
}

public static class MultiSelectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    AppCompatTextView indicator_number, indicator_en_tv, indicator_bn_tv, save_tv, select_data_tv;
    public MultiSelectHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.indicator_number = itemView.findViewById (R.id.indicator_number);
        this.indicator_en_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.indicator_en_tv);
        this.indicator_bn_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.indicator_bn_tv);
        this.select_data_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.select_data_tv);

        this.save_tv = itemView.findViewById (R.id.save_tv);
    }
}



@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    mContext = parent.getContext();

    if (viewType == 1){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_questionear_edittext_layout, parent, false);
        return new EdittextViewHolder(view);
    }if (viewType == 2){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_questionear_edittext_layout, parent, false);
        return new EdittextViewHolder(view);
    }if (viewType == 3){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_questionear_edittext_layout, parent, false);
        return new EdittextViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == 4){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_questionear_datepicker_layout, parent, false);
        return new DatePickerHolder(view);
    } else if(viewType == 5){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_questionear_spinner_layout, parent, false);
        return new SpinnerPickerHolder(view);
    } else if(viewType == 6){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_questionear_mulilist_layout, parent, false);
        return new MultiSelectHolder(view);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    switch (dataSet.get(position).getColumnDataType()) {
        case 1:
            return Indicator.INT_TYPE;
        case 2:
            return Indicator.VARCHAR_TYPE;
        case 3:
            return Indicator.DECIMAL_TYPE;
        case 4:
            return Indicator.DATETIME_TYPE;
        case 5:
            return Indicator.BOOLEAN_TYPE;
        case 6:
            return Indicator.LIST_TYPE;
        default:
            return position;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Indicator beneficiaryIndicator = dataSet.get(position);

    if (beneficiaryIndicator !=null){
        int i = 0;
        List<String> values = beneficiaryIndicator.getValues();


        if (beneficiaryIndicator != null) {

            switch (beneficiaryIndicator.getColumnDataType()) {
                case Indicator.INT_TYPE:
                    break;

                case Indicator.VARCHAR_TYPE:
                    break;

                case Indicator.DECIMAL_TYPE:
                
                    break;

                case Indicator.DATETIME_TYPE:
                    
                    break;

                case Indicator.BOOLEAN_TYPE:
                    break;

                case Indicator.LIST_TYPE:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `append()` method creates a new array instance and returns it, but you don't do anything with the returned array so the Adapter is still looking at an empty array. You need to make the Adapter's `dataSet` property a public `var`. When you have a new array, set it to the Adapter's property and then call `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` so it knows it needs to refresh itself.

The other problem you'll run into is that your `append()` method returns an Array with a nullable type. If you want to stick with the Array class, you would need to convert it to an Array with non-nullable type.

However, the List class should be preferred to the Array class anyway. It limits the opportunities for misusing it or making mistakes. And you can easily create new lists with appended items just by using the `+` operator. For example:

```
with(adapter) {
    dataList = dataList + ParameterText("Temperature", "24°C")
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

After you get comfortable with using Adapter, you might want to transition to ListAdapter, which will perform better by automatically updating only the rows of data that change, but is a little more complicated to initially set up.

Comment: You were right about the `append()` method. But I used the List class instead of the Array class and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I’d have to see your new code to see what went wrong.

Comment: I edited my first question with my new code

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you've posted that would cause it not to show, so it must be a problem elsewhere. Though it is very odd to use a `List<Parameter?>` instead of `List<Parameter>`, and then have to use `!!`, which is almost always a code smell.

Comment: Indeed, using ˋ!!` was not appropriate. Even if it still doesn’t work, thank you for your help!